# How to return NA when nls model is unable to fit data?

Tags: r, tidyverse, nls

I am applying groupwise `nlsLM` model and solving it to get the x value when the y is highest individually for each group. But some of the studies are giving following error

> Error in `mutate()`:
> ℹ In argument: `model = map(data, ~nlsLM(y ~ SSlinp(x, a, b, xs), data = .x))`.
> Caused by error in `map()`:
> ℹ In index: 2.
> Caused by error in `nlsModel()`:
> ! singular gradient matrix at initial parameter estimates

How to avoid those studies and run for those studies where `nlsLM` model can be run?

Here is the code I am using with sample data

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gslnls)
library(broom)
library(minpack.lm)
library(nlraa)

df %>%
  nest(data = -SN) %>%
  mutate(model = map(data, ~ nlsLM(y ~ SSlinp(x, a, b, xs), data = .x))) %>% 
  mutate(x_opt = map(model, tidy)) %>%
  unnest(x_opt) %>% 
  filter(term %in% "xs") %>% 
  mutate(y_opt = unlist(map2(estimate, model, ~predict(.y, list(x = .x))))) %>%
  select(SN, estimate, y_opt)
```

Data

```
df = structure(list(SN = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), x = c(0L, 60L, 90L, 120L, 150L, 0L, 60L, 
90L, 120L, 150L, 0L, 60L, 90L, 120L, 150L), y = c(3569.5, 6698.1, 
6595.2, 6834.4, 6966.7, 3649.7, 4895.1, 5162, 4443.5, 5038.9, 
4097.7, 5664.9, 5518.1, 7608.1, 8081.6)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-15L))
```

Comment: see `try()`, `tryCatch()`, or `purrr::safely`

Comment: ... and `group_walk` or `group_map` are possibilities as well.

Comment: Where it is unable to fit, it may return NAs. I have tried `tryCatch()` but failed.

Comment: Can you show us *how* you've tried `tryCatch()`, and what failed?  I don't usually bother with `tryCatch()`; I use `try()` and then put in an `if (inherits(prev_result, "try-error")) ...` at the next stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a clunky, partial solution.  You'd have to add a similar `my_predict` function that will return the right null/`NA` results if the model is bad.

Alternatively, you could break the pipeline after the model-fitting stage and get rid of the models that didn't work (e.g. `filter(!inherits(model, "try-error"))` or some such), then run `tidy`/`predict` without hassles on the remaining elements ...

```r
empty <- tibble(
    term = c("a", "b", "xs"),
    estimate = NA_real_,
    std.error = NA_real_,
    p.value = NA_real_
)
my_tidy <- function(m) {
    if (inherits(m, "try-error")) empty else broom::tidy(m)
}

df %>%
  nest(data = -SN) %>%
    mutate(model = map(data, ~ try(nlsLM(y ~ SSlinp(x, a, b, xs), data = .x)))) %>% 
    mutate(x_opt = map(model, my_tidy)) %>%
    unnest(x_opt) %>%
    filter(term %in% "xs")
```

Comment: I know; that's why I said it was a partial solution. To get to the `y_opt` solution, you'd have to write a `my_predict` function analogous to the `my_tidy` function here that returned some sensible result containing `NA` values if the model was a `try-error` object rather than a fitted model.  I got lazy/left it as an exercise for the reader ...